# android text size on tvdpi display

Tags: android, xml

I'm testing my app using android sdk emulator.
I've tested on nearly all of the different sizes & densities, and they all scale how I want them too.
however when testing `tvdpi 800X1280`, the `textSize` is just slightly too big to display correctly.

I've specified `values-normal`, `values-large` dimens.xml with correct text sizing.
and these do display correctly for the other displays using the 'normal' & 'large' resolutions with mdpi & hdpi.

I understand that tvdpi is between mdpi & hdpi, however when altering the text size values in these two dimens.xml (`res/values-normal/dimens.xml` & `res/values-large/dimens.xml`), no change is seen on tvdpi display. (I guess this gives me 2 questions)

**How** does android select the best resources for the given display?

&
**How** do you set a default text size for tvdpi displays?

Note. `res/values/dimens.xml` does not specify text size

Non-sucsesses: `values-large-tvdpi/`, `values-normal-tvdpi/`, `values-tvdpi/`

Comment: Have you tried placing your values in res/values-tvdpi/dimens.xml

Comment: yup. I don't think `res/values` can be linked to display density. just display size

Comment: I am not sure if that is a right statement have you read this anywhere?. I have used it myself and it has worked

Comment: @hoomi, sorry I just re-read. you can specify density to values. however values-tvdpi doesn't get picked up by android (at least in my case)

Comment: What is the device that you are trying on?

Comment: (emulated) nexus 7, 7.27" tvdpi 800X1280

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device?

Comment: of course (not tvdpi, just mdpi, hdpi & xhdpi). and everything scales correctly.